# Vb.Net to Salesforce Integration Error?

Tags: .net, vb.net, salesforce

I am connecting VB.Net to SFDC and fetch contact details display it in datagrid view in VB.net application.
While build my application I am getting Following error,

> Error:Type 'ApexApi1.SoapClient' is not defined.

This is my code:

```
Imports SFAPI_2.ApexApi1

    Public Class Form1
        Implements IDisposable

        Private Shared sessionId As String = "mysessionid"
        Private Shared serverUrl As String = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/34.0"


        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        End Sub


        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
            Dim records As ApexApi1.sObject() = getContactDetails()
            If records.Length <= 0 Then
                MsgBox("No records found!")
                Exit Sub
            End If

            ' Convert custom object to dataset to display properly in datagridview
            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
            ds = rowTodsContact(records)

            Dim TableView As DataView
            TableView = ds.Tables("ContData").DefaultView
            DataGridView1.DataSource = TableView
        End Sub

        Private Function getContactDetails() As ApexApi1.sObject()
            Try
                Dim lr As ApexApi1.LoginResult

                Using ss As ApexApi1.SoapClient = New ApexApi1.SoapClient

                    If sessionId Is Nothing Or sessionId = "" Then
                        ' Login Call
                        lr = ss.login(Nothing, "myusername", "mypassword" & "securitytoken")
                        If lr.passwordExpired Then
                            MsgBox("Password Expired")
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                        sessionId = lr.sessionId.ToString().Trim()
                        serverUrl = lr.serverUrl.ToString().Trim()
                    End If
                End Using

                ' Store SessionId in SessionHeader; We will need while making query() call
                Dim sHeader As ApexApi1.SessionHeader = New ApexApi1.SessionHeader
                sHeader.sessionId = sessionId

                ' Variable to store query results
                Dim qr As ApexApi1.QueryResult = New ApexApi1.QueryResult
                Using ss1 As ApexApi1.SoapClient = New ApexApi1.SoapClient
                    ss1.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Address = New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(serverUrl)
                    ' Limit to display only 100 records
                    ss1.query(sHeader, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "SELECT AccountId, OwnerId, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact LIMIT 100", qr)
                End Using

                Dim records As ApexApi1.sObject() = qr.records
                Return records
            Catch ex As Exception

                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Function
        Private Function rowTodsContact(ByVal records() As ApexApi1.sObject) As DataSet
            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
            Try
                ds.Tables.Add("ContData")
                ds.Tables("ContData").Columns.Add("AccountId", GetType(String))
                ds.Tables("ContData").Columns.Add("OwnerId", GetType(String))
                ds.Tables("ContData").Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(String))
                ds.Tables("ContData").Columns.Add("LastName", GetType(String))
                ds.Tables("ContData").Columns.Add("Email", GetType(String))
                For i As Integer = 0 To records.Length - 1
                    Dim con As ApexApi1.Contact = DirectCast(records(i), ApexApi1.Contact)
                    Dim accId As String = con.AccountId
                    Dim ownerId As String = con.OwnerId
                    Dim fName As String = con.FirstName
                    Dim lName As String = con.LastName
                    Dim email As String = con.Email
                    ds.Tables("ContData").Rows.Add(accId, ownerId, fName, lName, email)
                Next
                Return ds
            Catch ex As Exception

                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Function


        Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Import statement alias, like ...

```
Imports ApxSpi1 = SFAPI_2.ApexApi1
```

... then, rebuild after using the ApxSpi1 alias where you currently use ApexApi1.